# speed up this Standard Deviation method

Tags: objective-c, c, nsdecimalnumber, standard-deviation

I have this method to calculate the standard deviation of an array of NSNumber integers, given a mean. The calculation uses NSDecimals to retain the highest resolution. This is currently demanding many cpu cycles, any help to speed it up while retaining the resolution required is appreciated! Thank you.

```
-(NSDecimal)standardDeviationOf:(NSMutableArray *)array withMean:(NSDecimal)mean {

if (![array count]) return CPTDecimalFromInt(0);

NSDecimal sumOfSquaredDifferences = CPTDecimalFromInt(0);


for (NSNumber *number in array) {

    NSDecimal valueOfNumber = CPTDecimalFromInt([number intValue]);
    NSDecimal difference = CPTDecimalSubtract(valueOfNumber, mean);
    sumOfSquaredDifferences = CPTDecimalAdd(sumOfSquaredDifferences, CPTDecimalMultiply(difference, difference));

}

return CPTDecimalFromDouble(
                            sqrt(
                                 CPTDecimalDoubleValue(sumOfSquaredDifferences) / [[NSNumber numberWithInt:[array count]] doubleValue]
                                 )
                            );
}
```

Comment: Have you profiled your code with Instruments to see where the slowdown is? My guess would be all the conversions you're doing between `intValue` and `NSDecimal`. Might you be better off using `NSDecimalNumber` for the inner loop and doing `NSDecimalNumber difference = [valueOfNumber decimalNumberBySubtracting:mean];`? (You'll need to convert some things from `NSDecimal` to `NSDecimalNumber` first.)

Comment: Since you end up converting to `double` to perform the square root, are you really gaining any precision by doing all the loop arithmetic with `NSDecimal` instead of just `double`?

Comment: DOn't useNSDecimal, just float or double. The point of decimal arithmetic is to have exact base-10 decimal numbers, mainly for financial transactions. There is no more inherent accurate for an application such as yours.

Comment: 90% of the time is being spent in these 2 lines:                  NSDecimal valueOfNumber = CPTDecimalFromInt([number intValue]);
sumOfSquaredDifferences = CPTDecimalAdd(sumOfSquaredDifferences, CPTDecimalMultiply(difference, difference));</br>

Answer (score 0):

An `NSDecimal` has 38 digits of precision, whereas `double` has roughly 16 digits of precision. But at the end of your loop, when you convert `sumOfSquaredDifferences` to `double` for the `sqrt` function, all the extra precision you had in the `NSDecimal` is "lost". You might as well perform the arithmetic of your inner loop using `double`, which should be much faster than `NSDecimal`:

```
double sumOfSquaredDifferences = 0;
double valueOfMean = [mean doubleValue];
for (NSNumber *number in array) {

    double valueOfNumber = [number intValue];
    double difference = valueOfNumber - valueOfMean;
    sumOfSquaredDifferences += difference * difference;

}

return CPTDecimalFromDouble(sqrt(sumOfSquaredDifferences /
                                 double([array count])));
```

Comment: I would like to do the square root as decimal also, but don't know any methods. You're correct that the precision is lost this way.

Comment: A quick web search led me to this blog post on computing the square root an an NSDecimalNumber: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/05/square-root-numerical-fun-with.html

Comment: If you're computing the standard deviation from a bunch of 32-bit integers, and 32-bit integers only have roughly 10 decimal digits of precision, why do you need to do the standard deviation arithmetic in `NSDecimal`? It doesn't make sense. You might as well do all the arithmetic in `double` and convert to NSDecimal after you're all done.